# upgrading features from drupal6 to drupal7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, upgrade

Is it possible to upgrade the modules created by features module on drupal6 to drupal7?If yes, please lemme know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

not Exactly..but hav a look on this http://drupal.org/project/coder  module